# AngularJS: Disable or remove ng-scope and ng-binding from generated HTML

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to remove ng-scope and ng-binding attribute values which are added dynamically in HTML generated by AngularJS ?

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students" ng-class="isGrey[$index]" ng-click="toggleClass($index)" class="ng-scope">
     <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
     <td class="ng-binding">Mahesh</td>
     <td class="ng-binding">Sapkal</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes,

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

Documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production

Comment: An small gotcha: that code will only work in angular 1.3+, the ability to disable the debug data was not present in 1.2 and previous versions of angular

Comment: I'm using 1.2.5, do you have any clue if it's worth to move to a higher angular version for the alibity to remove the debug info?

Comment: @Chen that question is very specific to your project - hard for me to judge from the outside. However, with this flag enabled the Angular team believes you will get at least a 33% increase in performance so YMMV. If your project is slow(ish) in production then it might be worth a look. Newer versions also have a ton of fixes, etc that might also fix a bunch of issues with your solution. We recently upgraded our project from 1.3 to 1.5 and we're glad we did.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, It's worth trying